# Possible to change Window background colour of a Dialog without a theme?

Tags: android, background, drawable

At the moment I extend a `Dialog` and use the constructor `Dialog(Context context, int theme)` to set the background colour via a theme. This dialog is an overlay, so it sits above everything showing on the screen. The theme is as follows:

```
<style
  name="Theme.example"
  parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_color</item>
</style>
```

Note that this theme sets the background colour via the `android:windowBackground` attribute. I need the **entire screen** to change colour, including the notification bar. But I also want to be able to change the background dynamically in Java after the dialog is displayed. The best way I've come up with is using `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background)`, where the `Drawable` is just a single pixel of the colour I want.

Is there a better way to do this? My current method works fine, but it would be nice to be able to use colours that I haven't predefined in `R.drawable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with the [`ColorDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) class.

You can create a new instance of the `ColorDrawable` class and set it as the background. Whenever you need to change the color you can just call `setColor(int color)`
 on that class.

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable();
// ColorDrawable colorDrawable =
//     new ColorDrawable(0xFF00FF00);    // With a custom default color.

colorDrawable.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
```